# How will I handle JSON key with dash/hypen in Retrofit?

Tags: android, parsing, formatting, retrofit

Below is an example response I got from the server.

```
"request": {
    "authenticate-login": {
        "response": {
            "status": 1,
            "msg": "User Authorized!"
        }
    }
}
```

I have used Retrofit for a quite some time now and it's my first to encounter such issue.

Comment: if it is the exact response from server then its not proper JSON response

Comment: THAT JSON SHOULD BE LIKE THIS : {
    "request": {
        "authenticate-login": {
            "response": {
                "status": 1,
                "msg": "UserAuthorized!"
            }
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Gson builder](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for json conversion in retrofit.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
        .create();
RestAdapter restAdapter = RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(Config.BASE_URL)
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
            .build;
```

In the other way, You can simply set `@SerializedName("")` annotation in your POJO.